# Upload file image validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have these codes as my validation before someone can upload an image. however when i try to upload different files like video files and etc. it is still pushing through? what am i missing here? here is my whole code behind. im not sure what you are looking for im sorry. its just its accepting everything that i try to upload and it uploads it but no image.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["IslandGasAdminPM"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GetCategories();

                AddSubmitEvent();
            }
            if (Request.QueryString["alert"] == "success")
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Record saved successfully')</script>");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx");
        }
    }
    private void AddSubmitEvent()
    {
        UpdatePanel updatePanel = Page.Master.FindControl("AdminUpdatePanel") as UpdatePanel;
        UpdatePanelControlTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = btnSubmit.UniqueID;

        updatePanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
    }
    private void GetCategories()
    {
        ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart();
        DataTable dt = k.GetCategories();
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlCategory.DataValueField = "CategoryID";
            ddlCategory.DataTextField = "CategoryName";
            ddlCategory.DataSource = dt;
            ddlCategory.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile != null)
        {
            SaveProductPhoto();

            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                ProductName = txtProductName.Text,
                ProductImage = "~/ProductImages/" + uploadProductPhoto.FileName,
                ProductPrice = txtProductPrice.Text,
                ProductDescription = txtProductDescription.Text,
                CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue),
                TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(txtProductQuantity.Text)
            };
            k.AddNewProduct();
            ClearText();
            Response.Redirect("/Admin/AddNewProduct.aspx?alert=success");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please upload photo');</script>");
        }
    }
    private void ClearText()
    {
        uploadProductPhoto = null;
        txtProductName.Text = String.Empty;
        txtProductPrice.Text = String.Empty;
        txtProductDescription.Text = String.Empty;
        txtProductQuantity.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    private void SaveProductPhoto()
    {
        if (uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile != null)
        {
            string filename = uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
            string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadProductPhoto.FileName);

            //check filename length
            if (filename.Length > 96)
            {
                Response.Write("Image should not exceed 96 characters");
            }
            //check file type
            else if (fileExt != ".jpg" && fileExt != ".jpeg" && fileExt != ".png" && fileExt != ".bmp")
            {
                Response.Write("Only jpg,jpeg,bmp and png are allowed");
            }
            //check file size
            else if (uploadProductPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4000000)
            {
                Response.Write("Image should not exceed 4MB");
            }
            //Save images to folder
            else
            {
                uploadProductPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages/" + filename));
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is pushed filename in "ProductImages" folder? Are you getting fileExt or it is empty?

Comment: im not sure abt your question. i updated my whole query and includes the whole code behind sir

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be creating a variable 'filename' and then not using it in the next line when you attempt to get the extension. I'm not aware of the detail of what you're doing, but that's an immediate red flag for me and might be involved.

If you can provide some examples of the value of the 'filename' and 'uploadProductPhoto.FileName' then I'll be able to help you work out what's going on.

Comment: im not sure what you are looking for @jayp but i have edit my question codes. its the whole code behind. please help me

Comment: He is saying to replace your line `string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(uploadProductPhoto.FileName);
` with `string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);`

Comment: tried it but its still accepting files even if not image file types sir @amit

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression validation control ,The expression for video formats is:

```
ValidationExpression=/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.avi|.AVI|.WMV|.wmv|.wav|.WAV|.mpg|.MPG|.mid|.MID|.asf|.ASF|.mpeg|.MPEG)$/
```

The regular expression to validate audio file formats is:

```
ValidationExpression=/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.mp3|.MP3|.mpeg|.MPEG|.m3u|.M3U)$/
```

**Edit:** The regular expression to validate image file formats is:

```
ValidationExpression=/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.jpeg|.JPEG|.gif|.GIF|.png|.PNG|.JPG|.jpg|.bitmap|.BITMAP)$/
```

and:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadVideo" runat="server" />           
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator7"

 runat="server" ControlToValidate="fileUploadVideo"

ErrorMessage="Only .avi, .mpg, .wav, .mid, .wmv, .asf and .mpeg Video formats are allowed." ForeColor="Red"

ValidationExpression="/^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))+(.avi|.AVI|.WMV|.wmv|.wav|.WAV|.mpg|.MPG|.mid|.MID|.asf|.ASF|.mpeg|.MPEG)$/"

ValidationGroup="PartnerProfileUpdate" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

See [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/validation-for-file-upload-control-in-Asp-Net/) link for complete article.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `SaveProductPhoto` does not throw exception when checked failure,there is two way to avoid your problem:

1. throw exception
2. add `Response.End()` below your `Response.Write` code

also, validate the file ext is not a good idea,you can validate the InputStream,read the first two byte,and check them

```
//byte[] bytes = new byte[2];  
//string.Format("{0}{1}",bytes[0],bytes[1])  
//255216 is jpg;7173 is gif;6677 is BMP,13780 is PNG;7790 is exe,8297 is rar
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it out using regex. here is the expression.

```
ValidationExpression="^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|doc|DOC|pdf|PDF|PNG|png)$"
```